# Javascript move input text into another tag

Tags: javascript, html, input

I'm trying to take a value, a letter, and move that value to another location within the document. So if an 't' is typed into the text-box I want to move that value entered into the `<p>` tag just above? I'm not sure how to be more descriptive so I've included my html and javascript code below.

FYI I'm in a programming bootcamp we're using pure Javascript for this assignment and not JQuery and I'm also completely new to this so please excuse me if this is a stupid question. Here's what I have so far

`

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
<body>

    <h1>The Psychic Game</h1>
    <h2>Guess what letter I'm thinking of.</h2>
    <h3 id="wins">Wins:</h3>
    <h3 id="losses">Losses:</h3>
    <h3 id="guess">Guess Left:</h3>
    <h3 id="guess_num">Your Guesses so Far: <p id="guess_val"> </p></h3>
    <form>
        <input type="text" name="guess_letter" value="">
    </form>
</body>

</html>`

`var guessLetter = document.getElementById("guess_letter");

    function letterPick(guessLetter){

    }
```

`

Answer (score 1):

What I am doing here is saving both of the elements we will use to variables. Then I am adding the keyup event listener to the input field. Every time a key is pressed we want to change in the `innerHTML` of the p tag.

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
<body>

    <h1>The Psychic Game</h1>
    <h2>Guess what letter I'm thinking of.</h2>
    <h3 id="wins">Wins:</h3>
    <h3 id="losses">Losses:</h3>
    <h3 id="guess">Guess Left:</h3>
    <h3 id="guess_num">Your Guesses so Far: <p id="guess_val"> </p></h3>
    <form>
        <input type="text" name="guess_letter" value="">
    </form>
    <script>
        var input = document.querySelector('[name="guess_letter"]');
        var p = document.getElementById('guess_val');

        input.addEventListener('keyup', (e) => {
          p.innerHTML = e.currentTarget.value;
        });
    </script>
</body>
</html>
```

```js
var input = document.querySelector('[name="guess_letter"]');
var p = document.getElementById('guess_val');

input.addEventListener('keyup', (e) => {
  p.innerHTML = e.currentTarget.value;
});
```

```html
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
<body>

    <h1>The Psychic Game</h1>
    <h2>Guess what letter I'm thinking of.</h2>
    <h3 id="wins">Wins:</h3>
    <h3 id="losses">Losses:</h3>
    <h3 id="guess">Guess Left:</h3>
    <h3 id="guess_num">Your Guesses so Far: <p id="guess_val"> </p></h3>
    <form>
        <input type="text" name="guess_letter" value="">
    </form>

</body>

</html>
```